# Socket.io ID and user info security

Tags: node.js, socket.io

What I want to do at the moment is when user leaves lobby I want to emit the username who left the lobby and then display that info in lobby chatroom. This is the current emit:

```
  $("#lobby-leave-btn").on('click', () => {
    socket.emit('lobby-left', {
      username: username
    });
  });
```

The problem is that everyone can set whatever username they want in console, even if I check in serverside if the username exists in DB they can type existing users username who is not in lobby.

Is there somehow possible way to do this without passing username ? More secure way ? I can get `socket.id` in serverside but then again I can't get user info by socket id. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why not check the username they type in when they try to connect?

Comment: Connect where ?

Comment: connect to the socket?

Answer (score 0):

If you have usernames, then you should have them stored server-side, which I assume you're doing (either in a database, or just stored in memory on the server when the users connect). In that case, as soon as you know who a user is -- that is, as soon as they either sign in (if you have a sign-in system) or connect to the socket -- you should store the username as a property on the socket itself on the server. Then any socket data that comes in will automatically have the username attached to it, since it's inherently connected to that socket.

The mantra of web security is that you should never trust user-submitted data if you can help it; so you should never let the user identify themselves in an action without some sort of verification. Hence, verify them once on sign-in or connection, then store their identity on the socket, don't let them tell you who they are whenever they want to make a change.

Comment: Yeah okay I have this in mind also. But I should then from login store info into variable ? And then I could easily reuse the same variable with user info ?

Comment: Like I said, it's best to store the identifying information (like a username) as a property on the socket object itself, on the server. This way, all data coming from the socket connection will automatically identify who's sending it (because you always know which socket is receiving the data, and the user info is on that socket), and when the socket closes, that data is destroyed with it, so no one can continue impersonating them. (In my own app, I also use a token system, but that's not completely necessary for your purposes.)

Comment: How I should exactly assign info to the socket parameter ?

Comment: The socket is ultimately just a Javascript object; you can add whatever parameters you want to it like any other object. So for instance, if your socket variable is called `sock`, you can just do `sock.socketUsername = "abraom_185"`, and from then on you could get the username by accessing `sock.socketUsername`. (Of course, don't hard-code the name; get it from the user when they sign in, or connect, or however they supply their username the first time.)

Comment: `io.on('connection', (socket) => {` So I can assing info to this `socket` parameter ? I did this `socket.socketUsername = data.username;` (I get username) in login socket, but then when I want to reuse it in another socket, I get `undefined`

Comment: That's correct. Why are you trying to access it from *another* socket? Each user should only need one socket for themselves. Why are you opening multiple sockets for the same user?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186736/discussion-between-abraom-185-and-icemetalpunk).